# How can I use AOP for Blazor assemblies?

Tags: c#, aop, blazor, fody

What are the possibilities to process Blazor C# compiled code (Wasm) reusing weavers that worked on .NET Standard assemblies (e.g. Fody).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... to process Blazor C# compiled code (Wasm)

Blazor does not compile C# to Wasm.

The IL files are deployed to the Browser. So you might be in luck here, if you get the tooling set up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Fody does support Blazor.